# appDelegate does not have a member called 'PlayerName'

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I'm trying to get a variable to replace the label text.

I created the label using the drag and drop feature and then also Ctrl + Drag to the viewcontroller.swift file to create it there. Which gave me this:

```
@IBOutlet var playerName: UILabel!
```

Now, in myAppDelegate.swift file, just in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function I added:

```
self.playerName.text = "textHere"
```

However, When I run the App I get the above error. What step have I missed?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you setting text to the label from AppDelegate, you should do that in your ViewController's viewDidLoad method,

Or if you are insisting, the line you wrote

```
self.playerName.text = "textHere"
```

"self" is pointing to AppDelegate and your UILabel playerName is a member of the class ViewController.

You have to create an instance of your ViewController to set the text to your label from AppDelegate

Comment: There is a function in my appdelegate that gets the data from Parse.com - If the value == "yes" I want the label to change to yes. How would I do that? Thanks for the reply too :)

Comment: yes it can be done, but as I said you need to create an instance of ViewController like this 

let vcObj : ViewController = ViewController()

and then do this to set text to your label 

vcObj.playerName.text = "textHere"